# Merging PHP arrays and nest relations

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, array-merge

I have two arrays in PHP that I need to pass in to a JS script. The PHP arrays are `locations` and `rooms` as follows:

**var_dump($locations)**

```
Array ( [0] => Array 
               ( [id] => 1
                 [name] => "London"  )
        [1] => Array 
               ( [id] => 2
                 [name] => "Manchester"  )
      )
```

**var_dump($rooms)**

```
Array ( [0] => Array 
               ( [id] => 1
                 [locationId] => "1"
                 [name] => "Lon Room 1"  )
        [1] => Array 
               ( [id] => 2
                 [locationId] => "1"
                 [name] => "Lon Room 2"  )
        [2] => Array 
               ( [id] => 3
                 [locationId] => "1"
                 [name] => "Lon Room 3"  )
        [3] => Array 
               ( [id] => 4
                 [locationId] => "2"
                 [name] => "Man Room 1"  )
        [4] => Array 
               ( [id] => 5
                 [locationId] => "2"
                 [name] => "Man Room 2"  )
      )
```

I need to merge the rooms array in to the locations array grouping rooms under their appropriate locations so that I am able to spit out the following syntax to a JS plugin called DailyPlot Scheduler.

```
{ name: "London", id: "1", children:[
         { name : "Lon Room 1", id : "1" },
         { name : "Lon Room 2", id : "2" },
         { name : "Lon Room 3", id : "3" }
         ] 
 },
 { name: "Manchester", id: "2", children:[
         { name : "Man Room 1", id : "1" },
         { name : "Man Room 2", id : "2" }
         ] 
 }
```

I'm learning a few things here and there as part of my apprenticeship but am not good enough to wrap my head around this by myself just yet haha sorry and thank you!

Comment: The keys in `$locations` are different due a typo or they are ok? ( id+name, name+age )

Comment: Typo sorry! Good spot, I've corrected it.

Comment: I made about 20 attempts - none worked and all were very messy, didn't think it would help, sorry.

Comment: If these two arrays are the results of database queries, the two queries could most likely be rewritten as one with a join and the merged array could be created as you fetch the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an array that's indexed by location id, then you can use the index to add children for a specified location:

```
$locations_by_id = [];

foreach($locations as $location) {
    $location['children'] = []; //initialize children to an empty array
    $locations_by_id[$location['id']] = $location;
}

foreach($rooms as $room) {    
    //add room to location
    $locations_by_id[$room['locationId']]['children'][] = $room;
}

$locations = array_values($locations_by_id); //removes the id index

print json_encode($locations);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't even consider this when making my attempts! I've opted to accept fusion3k's answer as it seems a lot cleaner and I love the creativity of using array_column and indexing using array_search. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Arbiter Actually, FuzzyTree answer is more efficient than mine :)

Comment: Could you explain why? Is it that less functions are used? Thanks guys

Comment: @Arbiter because with my solution you use `array_search()` for each room. Virtually, if you have 5 locations and 5 rooms, with this solution you performs 5+5 operations, with mine 5*5 (this example is not correct at all, it's only to make the idea)

Answer (score 2):

I noticed in one of your comments that you are using a database, so I decided to go ahead and add an answer. One other option would be to avoid having two arrays to begin with by joining locations and rooms in your query. I made some assumptions about names of tables/columns, but a query like this should work:

```
SELECT l.id AS l_id, l.name AS l_name, r.id AS r_id, r.name AS r_name
FROM locations l LEFT JOIN rooms r ON l.id = r.locationId
ORDER BY l.id, r.id
```

Then as you fetch the rows from your results you can construct the array using the location ID as the key.

```
while ($room = $query->fetch()) { // fetch method depends on what db extension you're using
    $rooms[$room['l_id']]['name'] = $room['l_name'];
    $rooms[$room['l_id']]['id'] = $room['l_id'];
    $rooms[$room['l_id']]['children'][] = array('name' => $room['r_name'], 
                                                'id'   => $room['r_id']);
}

echo json_encode(array_values($rooms));
```

Comment: A really cool idea too, thank you! I would up vote for the input and suggestion but I can't yet :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array with all `id` of `locations` array, then you can add each `rooms` array directly to `locations` array using `array_search`:

```
$index = array_column( $locations, 'id' );
foreach( $rooms as $key => $val )
{
    $found = array_search( $val['locationId'], $index );
    $locations[$found]['children'][] = array( 'name' => $val['name'], 'id' => $val['id'] );
}

$json = json_encode( $locations );
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/DRr8J)**</kbd>

Comment: Really great idea thank you! Very creative. I haven't actually used the array_column and array_search functions before so this is a really cool example. I've tested this with my database and it works nicely, very pretty code.